# How to query managed triples stored in marklogic through tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, marklogic-9, triples

I have managed triples stored in my  marklogic database. I want to query them using sparql and provide visualisation through tableau. But I am not sure what will be view and schema name for managed triples in tableau as they are not created by TDE.

By  running the below  sparql query in new custom SQL I am getting below mentioned error 
Query:
Select  *
where {?s ?o ?p}

"Bad connecting:Tableau could not connect to the data source".

The #of binded parameters< the #of parameters markers.

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue and also guide me on
what is the correct way of querying managed triples stored in marklogic using tableau.

Comment: It looks like you need to do something like [this](https://medium.com/virtuoso-blog/virtuoso-tableau-sparql-f9411852a87d).

Comment: I tried to execute the below query as per the link mentioned above for Marklogic sql driver SELECT DISTINCT 
   data.subject        AS "subject", 
   data.object         AS "object", 
   data.predicate      AS "predicate"
   
FROM
(
  SPARQL
  
  SELECT ?subject
         ?object 
         ?predicate
         
  WHERE  
  { ?subject ?object ?predicate}) AS data, But still receiving the same error "The #of binded parameters< the #of parameters markers"

Comment: That sounds like a DB error not a Tableau error.  Can you run the same query outside of Tableau successfully?

Comment: i tried to execute outside the tableau but still getting errors.

Comment: Yes, then you definitely need to get the query right or it won't work in any tool.